# How to enable browserify with grunt for jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, npm, gruntjs, browserify

I'm getting

```
"Error: Cannot find module './core' from '/var/www/html/psychedharma/public_html/vendor'"
```

I don't normally use browserify but jquery-ui seems to require it (excuse the pun.)

Any help much appreciated.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

    grunt.initConfig({

        node: './node_modules',
        dest: './public_html/vendor',
        destfaf: './public_html/fonts',

        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [                    
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        flatten: true,
                        src: ['<%= node %>/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.*'],
                        dest: '<%= destfaf %>/', 
                        filter: 'isFile'
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        flatten: true,
                        src: ['<%= node %>/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.*'],
                        dest: '<%= destfaf %>/', 
                        filter: 'isFile'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        concat: {           
            css: {
                files: {
                    '<%= dest %>/css.css': [
                        '<%= node %>/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                        '<%= node %>/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
                    ]
                }
            },
            js: {
                files: {
                    '<%= dest %>/js.js': [
                        '<%= node %>/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                        '<%= node %>/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                        '<%= node %>/less/dist/less.min.js',
                        '<%= node %>/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
                        '<%= node %>/jquery-ui/sortable.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        browserify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= dest %>/js.js': ['<%= dest %>/js.js']
                },
                // options: {
                //     transform: ['coffeeify']
                // }   
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            build: {
                files: {
                    '<%= dest %>/js.min.js': [ '<%= dest %>/js.js' ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('def', [
        'concat',
        'copy',
        'browserify',
        'uglify'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['def']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the fix.

First of all I used a jquery UI tag from the official repo:

```
npm install --save github:jquery/jquery-ui#1.11.4
```

Then I replaced the lines:

```
'<%= node %>/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
'<%= node %>/jquery-ui/sortable.js'
```

with:

```
'<%= node %>/jquery-ui/ui/core.js',
'<%= node %>/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js',
'<%= node %>/jquery-ui/ui/mouse.js',
'<%= node %>/jquery-ui/ui/sortable.js'
```

It looks like browserify won't be required after all.